# NXT ROS nxt_ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, was following NXT ROS tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/nxt_ros/Tutorials/Getting%20started after following this install http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/NXT/electric and also the nxt-python-2.2.2.zip,when i tryed to create the package:roscreate-pkg learning_nxt rospy nxt_ros ,it gives the ERROR: dependency [nxt_ros] cannot be found do i have to add some path to nxt-python or do i have to install something that i am missing?

thanks for any help given.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46451/nxt-ros-nxt_ros/) by [H.C](https://answers.ros.org/users/3434/h.c/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-10-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-10-22**:
Which operating system are you running?

**Comment by [H.C](https://answers.ros.org/users/3434/h.c/) on 2012-10-24**:
afther the aswer below,                                                                                                          sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-nxtall, with this commands i have allready installed also the Electric version or would i have to chance anythingmore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am using Ubuntu 11.10 in a virtual machine,i was told also that it my be because of the version of ROS(it still doesnt have support for the last version of ROS),so that i should use ROS Electric.i am a beginner at ROS,so the most recent version of ROS is the fuerte?and i should chance to Electric and that would fix the problem then?? or it doesnt have to to with the version?

---

Originally posted by [H.C](https://answers.ros.org/users/3434/h.c/) with karma: 16 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0